# Electron Getting Files into the Right Place

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron

I'm new to using Electron so I'm probably missing something rather simple. I'm trying to implement some simple routing in my Electron app using react-router-dom but it doesn't seem like my program can find the right files. Looking at the dev tools, the structure looks like this:
[app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaSmM.png). I have a React component that I'm trying to access as follows:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
            <Route path='ConfigurationEditor' element={<ConfigurationEditor />} />
        </Routes>
    </HashRouter>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I click on a button that changes the window location to "/ConfigurationEditor", I get an error like: `Failed to load URL: file:///ConfigurationEditor with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.
Looking back at the structure, this makes sense because the [files for that component are buried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbXyH.png) in either the `top/.` or `top/syntax-configuration-editor` folders, not the `file://` folder.

How do I get those folders under file:// (assuming that's the correct thing to do)?

---

Other potentially helpful/relevant info

- The window is created through `window.loadFile('index.html')`.
- In my `package.json`, the `"homepage"` field is set to `"./"`, and the `"build"` field looks as follows:

```
"asar": true,
"files": [
      "**/*",
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json",
      "dist/main.js"
    ],
```

- The UI component:

```
<Button className={styles.buttonStyle}
variant='contained'  
size='large'
color='primary'
fullWidth
onClick={(e) = {e.preventDefault;window.location.href="/ConfigurationEditor"}}
>
Configurations
</Button>
```

Comment: How are you navigating to `"/ConfigurationEditor"` within the app? Can you add the relevant UI code being used? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese With an onClick() function, I edited the above to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ConfigurationEditor` is supposed to be a React component, then the `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, i.e. `element={<ConfigurationEditor />}`.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
      <Route path='ConfigurationEditor' element={<ConfigurationEditor />} />
    </Routes>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

### Update

Try using the `useNavigate` hook and use `navigate("/ConfigurationEditor")` instead of the hard reload using `window.location.href` is going to do. When the page is reloaded attempting to access a sub-route it seems Electron is expecting to find a file at that location. Using the `navigate` function doesn't reload the page and keeps the app running on `"/"` and handling routes/pages internally.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

<Button className={styles.buttonStyle}
  variant='contained'  
  size='large'
  color='primary'
  fullWidth
  onClick={(e) = {
    e.preventDefault;
    navigate("/ConfigurationEditor");
>
  Configurations
</Button>
```